# ! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package hyperref

Tags: hyperref, arxiv, option-clash

I am trying to upload my publication(which is in ACL2019 format) to arXiv. But I am getting the following error:

```
 ! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package hyperref.
```

In my main tex file I am using the following packages:

```
\pdfoutput=1
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[hyperref]{acl2019}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{url}
```

This code is compiling in overleaf, but I am having problem while uploading it to arXiv.

Could anyone help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have not provided a usable test file to debug but did you upload the acl2029 package? The error means hyperref was loaded twice but the fragment you show does not show that

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thanks for your reply. Actually arXiv adds an other hyperref package of its own while uploading. So i think that is causing a conflict

Comment: it is impossible to test the fragment you have posted but try removing the `[hyperref]` option to your package and let arxiv handle that